# Return a list with parseString

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyparsing

Hi guys I'm working on a parser that needs to create a dictionary with a certain format. pyparsing is capable of returning a list?

```py
parser = Combine(Suppress('(') + Word(nums) + Suppress(')')).setParseAction(lambda toks: list(toks))
>>> parser.parseString("""(1)""")
(['1'], {})
```

The expected format i need is:

```py
>>> parser.parseString("""(1)""")
([['1']], {})
```

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: pyparsing returns a rich object of type ParseResutls, which can be accessed as a list, as a dict, or as an object with attributes. To reflect this multiple personality, the parsed data is shown as it would be as a list and as a dict, so a tuple of those two views is the repr format that you see when calling parseString in the Python interactive repl. As a list, you can get `['1']`; as a dict, there are no defined results names, so the dict-like view is empty. But you do earn good marks for using a parse action in your parser - parse actions are a powerful feature in creating pyparsing work.

Comment: Looking further at the docstrings in pyparsing, I see that I could be clearer on this subject, as to just what you get back from calling ParserElement.parseString - changes committed and pushed.]

Comment: More info on ParseResults here: https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyparsing.html#pyparsing.ParseResults